# fetching data using 2 references in c# windows form

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

can someone help me?
I have a bulk data with several column where there is column name "NamaStasiun" (StationName) and "Tanggal" (Date). I want to fetch my data based on those 2 categories simultaneously where the stationname is in a combobox and date using 2 datetimepicker.

here is my code

```
private void DisplayDataGrid()
{

     SqlCommand query2 = new SqlCommand("select NamaStasiun, Tanggal , 
     Hour00, Hour01, etc, Hour23 from [TableName] where Namastasiun like                            
     '%" + comboBoxNamaStasiun.Text + "', Tanggal between          
     '"+DatePickerAwal.Value.ToShortDateString()+"' and 
     '"+DatePickerAkhir.Value.ToShortDateString()+"'", connection);
        
     SqlDataAdapter dataadapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        
     DataTable datatable2 = new DataTable();
       
     dataadapter2.SelectCommand = query2;
        
     datatable2.Clear();
        
     dataadapter2.Fill(datatable2);
        
     datagridshowdataexport.DataSource = datatable2;
   
}
```

and it replied me with message "Incorrect syntax near ','."

But when I use only NamaStasiun as reference, it was work normally.

Thank you.

Comment: There seems to be a AND missing in your where clause before Tanggal.Looks like you thought the different conditions in the where clause are separated by commas but they aren't you need to use a boolean operator to connect those conditions like AND and OR. Besides that you should use Parameters for the values needed in the SQL query don't just concatenate stuff. Have a look in the ADO.Net documentation for parameters.

Comment: And you might want to try your sql in some database frontend first before using them within you program.